# Complexity of following algorithm for the Three-Sum-Problem

Tags: java, algorithm

Given is a sorted list (a[0],...,a[n-1]) of n integers. I need to find three **different** indices p, q, r such that the triplet (a[p],a[q],a[r]) satisfies the equation a[p]+a[q]+a[r]=0. Also, the sorted list can contain the same number more than once. The algorithm that is required needs to be **quadratic.**

I have found a solution (I'm definitely not saying that it is the most efficient one), but I'm quite sure that it's not quadratic (2 for-loops and a while-loop). Here is my code:

```
public ThreeSumIndices searchTriplet(List<Integer> list) {
    for(int i=0; i<list.size()-1; i++){
        int w = -list.get(i);
        for(int j=i+1; j<list.size(); j++){
            int k = 1;
            while(j+k<list.size() && list.get(j)+list.get(j+k)!=w){
                k++;
            }
            if(j+k==list.size()){
                k = 1;
            } else if(list.get(j)+list.get(j+k)==w){
                return new ThreeSumIndices(i,j,j+k);
            }
        }
    }
    return null; //no indices found.
}
```

*ThreeSumIndices is a seperate class. It returns the indices we're looking for in the form (p,q,r). Constructor parameters are three integer (= three indices).*

Example: (-5, 1, 2, 3, 7) --> (0,2,3).

I'm fairly new to complexity analysis, so I was wondering whether my guess of this algorithm not being quadratic was correct or not.

If so, is there a way to get rid of a loop? Or maybe there's an alternative, but more efficient algorithm?

Thanks.

Comment: how can be big your list ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the array is sorted then all you need to do is the following:

- Run loop from i=0 to n-2.
- Initialize two index variables l=i+1 and r=n-1
- while:l<r, if ((sum = arr[i]+arr[l]+arr[r]) == 0):You got your answer
- If sum is less than zero, increment l (l++), otherwise decrement r (r--)
- scan all the elements.

  ```
  for (int i=0; i < n-1; i++) {
      int l = i + 1; 
      int r = n - 1; 
      int x = arr[i]; 
      while (l < r){ 
          if (x + arr[l] + arr[r] == 0) print()
          else if(x + arr[l] + arr[r] < 0) l++;
          else r--; 
      } 
  }
  ```

The time complexity of this code will be O(n^2) with space complexity of O(1)

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve this for a coding interview, here's my python solution which has quadratic time complexity.

```
from collections import Counter

class Solution(object):
    def threeSum(self, nums):
        res = []
        counts = Counter(nums)
        num_counts = sorted(counts.items())

        # If we pick 3 of the same nums
        if counts[0] >= 3:
            res.append([0] * 3)

        for i, (first, first_count) in enumerate(num_counts):
            # Pick two of these and one greater
            if first_count >= 2 and first < 0 and -(first * 2) in counts:
                res.append([first, first, -(first * 2)])

            # Pick one and two greater
            for j in range(i + 1, len(num_counts)):
                second, second_count = num_counts[j]
                # Pick two of these as second and third num
                if second_count >= 2 and -first == 2 * second:
                    res.append([first, second, second])

                # Pick this as second num and third which is greater
                third = -(first + second)
                if third > second and third in counts:
                    res.append([first, second, third])

        return res
```

Basically, it counts the occurrences then sorts (number, count) tuples so that

`[-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4]`

becomes

`[(-4, 1), (-1, 2), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)]`

We then iterate trying to pick each number twice and third greater if possible and add that to the result. Then, we pick a number once and try to find two greater numbers which sum to zero.